# conditionally parsing json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract a value from a json array using python. How do I get the value for `"energy"` on a specific day? Here is what the json looks like:

```
{
  "emeter": {
    "get_daystat": {
      "day_list": [
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 1, "energy": 0.651000 },
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 2, "energy": 0.349000 },
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 3, "energy": 0.481000 }
      ],
      "err_code": 0
    }
  }
}
```

So for example, using:

```
parsed_json = json.loads(json)
```

how would I extract the `"energy"` value for `"year":2016, "month":10, "day":2`?

Comment: that isn't valid JSON. I'm assuming `json =` isn't in the JSON text string.

Comment: There's nothing conditional about the *parsing* here. Searching through a parsed data structure to extract a piece of it is a much, **much** easier problem than trying to conditionally parse (which is off in "subject of active CS research" land).

Comment: BTW, this is a rather unfortunate data structure. It would be vastly more efficient to search for a single value if this were `"get_daystat": { "year": { "2016": { "10": {"1": 0.651, "2": 0.349, "3": 0.481 } } }`

Comment: It is an unfortunate data structure but I have no control over it.

Comment: @Charles Duffy - if you have a better suggestion for the title of the question please let me know.

Comment: "Extracting a field from a Python data structure", perhaps? If the parsing works correctly (and nothing in your question currently appears to indicate otherwise), the fact that that data structure used to be JSON before it was parsed into Python is really quite irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parsed_json` will have a python dict. You can access the `day_list` array with a simple linear search.

```
def get_energy_value_by_date(obj, year, month, day):   
    for value in obj['emeter']['get_daystat']['day_list']:
        if value['year'] == year and value['month'] == month and value['day'] == day:
            return value['energy']


energy = get_energy_value_by_date(parsed_json, 2016, 10, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a linear search through the data:

```
def get_energy(data, year, month, day):
    for date in data['emeter']['get_daystat']['day_list']:
        if(date['year'] == year
           and date['month'] == month
           and date['day'] == day):
            return date['energy']

json_data = {
  "emeter": {
    "get_daystat": {
      "day_list": [
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 1, "energy": 0.651000 },
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 2, "energy": 0.349000 },
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 3, "energy": 0.481000 }
      ],
      "err_code": 0
    }
  }
}

print('{:1.6f}'.format(get_energy(json_data, 2016, 10, 2)))  # --> 0.349000
```

If there's no matching date, the function will effectively return `None`.

***Update***

If you have a lot of days in the `"day_list"` *and* they are ordered (sorted) by date as shown in your example, it would faster to take advantage of that and do a binary search rather than a linear one. Python includes the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) module, which can be used to do simple binary searches. Unfortunately none of the functions in it take optional arguments for controlling the comparisons like the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function does.

However this can be overcome by looking at the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py#l67) for the module and writing your own search function as illustrated below:

```
from datetime import datetime

def keyed_bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, keyfunc=lambda v: v):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    Like bisect.bisect_left but allows a keyfunc to extract key from each item.
    """
    x_key = keyfunc(x)
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi) // 2
        if keyfunc(a[mid]) < x_key:
            lo = mid+1
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo

def get_date(d):
    return datetime(d['year'], d['month'], d['day'])

def get_energy2(data, year, month, day):
    """Locate the first day exactly equal to the given date."""
    day_list = data['emeter']['get_daystat']['day_list']
    target = {'year': year, 'month': month, 'day': day}

    i = keyed_bisect_left(day_list, target, keyfunc=get_date)

    # return energy value if date found
    if i != len(day_list) and get_date(day_list[i]) == get_date(target):
        return day_list[i]['energy']

    raise ValueError('date not found')

print('{:1.6f}'.format(get_energy2(json_data, 2016, 10, 1)))
print('{:1.6f}'.format(get_energy2(json_data, 2016, 10, 2)))
print('{:1.6f}'.format(get_energy2(json_data, 2016, 10, 3)))
print('{:1.6f}'.format(get_energy2(json_data, 2016, 10, 4)))
```

Output:

```
0.651000
0.349000
0.481000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conditionally-parsing-json.py", line 67, in <module>
    print('{:1.6f}'.format(get_energy2(json_data, 2016, 10, 4)))  # --> ValueError
  File "conditionally-parsing-json.py", line 62, in get_energy2
    raise ValueError('date not found')
ValueError: date not found
```